# Form targetting an iframe is opening new tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I am trying to submit a form to an iframe both of which are constructed dynamically in my project using javascript.

```
<script>
document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('id', iframeId);
document.getElementById(iframeId).setAttribute('name', target);
document.getElementById(iframeId).setAttribute('width', width);
document.getElementById(iframeId).setAttribute('height', height);

document.querySelector('form').setAttribute('id', id);
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('target', target);
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('action', actionURL);

document.getElementById(id).submit();
<script>
```

This is how it looks later in the browser Web Inspector.

```
<iframe id="my_frame" name="my_frame" width="700" height="400">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<form id="my_form" target="my_frame" action="http://localhost:8080/MyProject/loadService" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="locale"/>
</form>
```

This works well for me in Firefox but in Chrome it opens a new tab. I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab) but it didn't resolve the issue. Can anyone please suggest what is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the iframe from your html and try doing like this:

```
//Create the iframe, set its attributes and append it before the form
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name = 'my_frame';
iframe.id = 'my_frame';
iframe.width = '400';
iframe.height = '700';
var form_element = document.getElementById('my_form');
form_element.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, form_element);

//Submit form to iframe
document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
```

Comment: The answer by @jeremypress was really helpful as well but this is more exhaustive. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484431/post-from-dynamic-form-to-dynamic-iframe-in-chrome-opens-a-new-window) post which fixed it for me. try dynamically generating the iframe, and make sure to set the name/id that will be targeted by the form BEFORE you append the iframe to the DOM.

example:

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name = 'target_name';
iframe.id = 'target_name';

// now append to DOM, ideally to a container element
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10478110/279833) suggests adding the target-attribute of the form dynamically before submitting the form.

Since you are creating both – the form and the iframe – dynamically, have you tried creating and adding the iframe to the DOM before the form?
Maybe the target-id has to exist on form-creation-time for it to work correctly.

Comment: I have the form and iframe created. What i do is just set the form attributes such as action url, target, id and iframe attributes such as name and id dynamically as I get it from the server and then submit the form. Have updated my question